# MySQL :: insert_id returning non zero value for a SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, insert, last-insert-id, mysql-insert-id

I've just spent the last 4 hours tracing a bug in my script. I kept receiving the following error:

`Call to a member function fetch_assoc on a non object`

This was being thrown when I did something like:

```
$query = $database -> query("SELECT .....")
while($q = $query) {...}
```

My `database -> query` method looks like: (where `$database -> mysqli` is the `mysqli` object)

```
function query($stmt) {
    $query = $this -> mysqli -> query($stmt);
    $id = $this -> mysqli -> insert_id;
    return $id === 0 ? $query : $id;
}
```

Now, this returns the inserted autoincrement id for an insert row, otherwise the result of the query. I just found out that if I run an insert query and then a select query, the second query will return the insert id of the insert query run beforehand. Is this really the intended behaviour, or am I missing something here?

Comment: last_insert_id() will return the auto_increment value of the last INSERT statement in the same session, whenever this was. I don't know what you expect here with using this function. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: From the docs: ` If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.`

Comment: MySQL is very clear: [LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) *With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a 64-bit value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.* There is even an example with a SELECT in between. What your API does, that may be a different story.

Comment: [PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php): *Returns the ID of the last inserted row, or the last value from a sequence object, depending on the underlying driver.* [mysqli::insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) *The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.*

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. I'm quoting the PHP docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: But even with mysqli: for me your code doesn't make sense to me. Please use the [rubber duck debugging method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :-)

Comment: My code is supposed to take a query and run it. If the query was an insertion, return the last insert id. If not, return what the query itself returns (asc. array with affected rows etc). From your MySQL description, it makes sense, but from the doc I linked to what is happening doesn't seem to be expected behaviour.

Comment: I don't see where this function simplifies things. So I wouldn't use it. But I could be wrong, I could overlooking something obvious too.

Comment: I've left out some other things its doing, mainly counting queries on the page. I just left in what was relevant to the question.